# How do I check if a submit is empty in a post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, base64

How do i check in a http post if my submit form is empty?
Since im saving it as base64 it wont let me post if the submit form is empty.

```
 $http.post('http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/api/key/profile', {
            picture: $scope.file.base64
            username: $scope.username
        })
```

Comment: what have you tried specifically to test whether your form is valid for a submit or not? Did you check values of the properties whose values you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["picture"]) && !empty($_POST["picture"]))
{
    echo "Yes, picture is set";    
}
else
{  
    echo "N0, picture is not set";
}
```

Comment: i need to check it before it gets posted, since i cant convert an empty submit to base64 "Cannot read property 'base64' of undefined"

Comment: is $scope a php variable ??